# Does a WPF Grid perform better than Winform's Table Layout Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, .net-3.5, grid

I am currently working on an application that uses a Table Layout Panel to display a row of data. Each row contains a certain number of textbox and checkbox.

The number of rows present is usually quite big, making the loading and navigation of the Table Layout Panel extremely slow.

After some research, I've found that the TLP is one of the slowest Winform UI controls and I'd like to implement a WPF Grid instead.

My question is two-fold:

1) Does a WPF Grid perform better than a Table Layout Panel when it comes to a large number of rows ?

2) Is it possible to include WPF controls in an application that uses exclusively winform controls ? (The application uses .NET 3.5)

Thanks for your time and have a great day.

Comment: Why not use DataGridView?  It's made for displaying rows of data...

Comment: Does the DataGridView perform better than the Table Layout Panel ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I checked, a DataGridView can't help me since the data that I display isn't just raw text. Each row is a combination of multiple textboxes. Not only that, but the textboxes respect a certain order and layout. They are not close to each other and of the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For performance, you'll have to do your own comparison.  There are so many factors that could affect it that a well-written WinForms could be faster than a poorly-written WPF or vice versa.  Just do a little prototyping and see if its an obvious win for you.

As far as using a little WPF in a mostly WinForms application, yes that is supported and can work well.  Just put your WPF content in a WPF `UserControl` and then add an `ElementHost` to your form and host the WPF control inside that.  Here's a lot more information:

- [Windows Forms – WPF Interoperability FAQ](http://windowsclient.net/learn/integration.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have background worker or thread for loading element into Table Layout Panel, if you have the problem with freezing?

Comment: Adding elements to the Table Layout Panel is not done using threads. I planned on adding multithreading, but manipulating (i.e: scrolling or resizing) the Table Layout Panel will still be slow, hence why I preferred implementing WPF from the get-go.